# Restart ElasticBeanstalk app server on schedule

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I created a lambda function using serverless in a private subnets of the non default VPC. I wanted to restart the app server of elasticbeanstalk application at a schedule time. I used boto3 and here is the reference [https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html][1]

The problem is that when i run the function locally it runs and restart the application server. But when i deploy using sls deploy, it is not working and i get null response back when i test it from the lambda console.

Here is the code:

```
import json
from logging import log
from loguru import logger
import boto3

    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz
    
    
        def main(event, context):
            try:
                client = boto3.client("elasticbeanstalk", region_name="us-west-1")
                applications = client.describe_environments()
                current_hour = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")).hour
                for env in applications["Environments"]:
                    applicationname = env["EnvironmentName"]
                    if applicationname == "xxxxx-xxx":
                        response = client.restart_app_server(
                            EnvironmentName=applicationname,
                        )
                        logger.info(response)
                        print("restarted the application")
        
                
             return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps("restarted the instance")}
       except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main("", "")
```

Here the serverless.yml file:

```
service: beanstalk-starter
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  profile: xxxx-admin
  region: us-west-1
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 15
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-xxxxxxxxxxx (open on all ports for inbound)
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (private)
      - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (private)


plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

functions:
  main:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - schedule: rate(1 minute)
```

Response from lambda console:

```
The area below shows the result returned by your function execution. Learn more about returning results from your function.
null
```

Any help would be appreciated! Let me know what I'm missing here!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I have to give these two permissions to my AWS lambda role from the AWS management console. You can also set the permission in the serverless.yml file.

1. AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
2. AWSCodePipeline_FullAccess

(*Make sure you are using the least privileges while giving permission to a role.)

Thank you.